# Reorganize on specific table and respective single index it is throwing an error

Tags: sql-server

Actually when we are doing reorganize on specific table along with single index we are facing below error

> Execution fail against SQL Server. SQL error number: 40197. Error Message: The service has encountered an error processing your request. Please try again. Error code 9001. A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded.

Used command to reorganize:

```
ALTER INDEX <Index-Name> ON <Table-Name> Reorganize
```

We are unable to find what the reason

Could someone please help us?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Azure by any chance?

Comment: Hi, Yeah  we are using ADF means  created stored procedure activity in from that we are calling store procedure which contains above alter reorganize command

Comment: You need to [edit] that information into your question, because its important.

Comment: Have you read https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/05/04/sql-azure-database-msg-40197-level-20-service-encountered-error-processing-request-please-try-error-code-40549/

Comment: yeah i have read this blog but i guess this blog is not use full

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.